# How do I burn a movie DVD on MacOS Catalina without additional software?

Tags: dvd-burning

I can burn a data DVD on MacOS Catalina but getting a movie DVD burned is escaping me.  Is this possible without additional software?

A VIDEO_TS folder is what I am looking to burn... VLC plays this perfectly including displaying the DVD menu.  How can I burn this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Sadly, since Apple discontinued iDVD, there is no built-in way to burn a movie DVD.

[Burn](https://burn-osx.sourceforge.io/Pages/English/home.html) is an excellent free utility for creating audio, video and file storage on optical media.

Comment: Thank you.  Unfortunately Burn has been quitting out on my unexpectedly.  Not sure the issue.

Comment: Latest version is 2.7.8. Make sure you're up-to-date. There are other apps if it doesn't work for you.

Comment: Even when iDVD was around, it was never built into the OS. iLife came preinstalled on lots of Macs, but if you did a clean install of e.g. Snow Leopard, it wouldn't have iDVD. I don't think there's ever been a "built in" way to make DVD-player-compatible DVDs.

Answer (score 2):

iMovie used to have "Burn to DVD".  iDVD let you do this and create a menu system.  But sadly those features are all gone.  Most computers no longer have a DVD/Blu-Ray burner/reader anymore.

Roxio Toast (commercial software ... so this ruins the "without additional software" part of your question) still seems to support this.  If you bomb out on no-cost options... this might be a (non-free) solution.

Answer (score 1):

> I can burn a data DVD on MacOS Catalina but getting a movie DVD burned is escaping me. Is this possible without additional software? A VIDEO_TS folder is what I am looking to burn...

Yes, it is possible to burn a VIDEO_TS to DVD (that will play in standard DVD players) without the use of any third-party software in Catalina. The following steps were tested under macOS 10.15.7 and Disk Utility 19.0 (1704):

1. Disk Utility → File → New Image → Image from Folder...
2. Select the parent folder of VIDEO_TS (which should not contain anything other than the VIDEO_TS directory) → Choose
3. Enter desired filename and location for the new disk image → select "DVD/CD master" as the Image Format → Save
4. Once the disk image has been saved, right click it in Finder and select "Burn Disk Image 'foo.cdr' to Disc..." → Burn

On a 7.4GB test directory, Disk Utility created a disk image of 8.55GB, while `hdiutil` created a disk image of just 7.4GB in one step: `hdiutil makehybrid -udf -udf-volume-name foo -o foo.iso /path/to/parent/dir/of/VIDEO_TS` (as above, the VIDEO_TS parent directory should not contain anything else).

Sources: Apple's [Create a disk image using Disk Utility on Mac](https://support.apple.com/guide/disk-utility/create-a-disk-image-dskutl11888/mac) and UCLA's [Burn DVD from VIDEO_TS folder (Mac OS X)](https://kb.ucla.edu/articles/burn-dvd-from-video_ts-folder-mac-os-x)

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying to use Burn to create save some home videos to DVD, but they won't play in my Samsung player.  I've tried burning to both DVD-R and DVD+R discs...both create discs that play just fine on my Mac using the built-in DVD player application, but when I pop those discs into my Samsung Blu-ray player, it ejects them with an error message saying something like "Can't play disc."

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. You’ve posted this as an answer, which is only for things that directly answer the question asked. If you have a different question, feel free to ask it using the Ask Question button at the top right.